# Why my jar works on windows and not on linux

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar, artifact

I am working on a Javafx application. I created the jar with intellij and artifact. The jar works very well on Windows. However when I run it on linux it displays this error message:

```
Erreur : impossible to find or load the main class view.View
Caused by : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

It's probably a stupid mistake but I've been stuck on it for a long time.....
I haven't found anything on the internet that could help me so if you have an idea or a useful link I'm very interested

Comment: What java version are you using? How do your dependencies look like. Please add these information to your question.

Comment: can you please post the content of the file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` from your jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already said that the Jar is working correctly on Windows, so it is packaged ok.

The only thing that might be going wrong on Linux may be one of below:

1. you made a mistake with the classname argument
2. the application's classpath is incorrectly specified
3. the wrong directory is on the classpath
4. the subdirectory path doesn't match the FQN
5. dependencies missing from the classpath
6. the class has been declared in the wrong package

**There can be also version mismatch**

Type the following on your terminal -

```
javac -version
```

If you get **javac 1.6.0_10** or later as the output then you will have to do the following steps. If you dont get the above output, you will have to un-install and re-install java.

Steps to do if version shown is 1.6.0_10 or later
Create symlink-

```
ln -s /usr/local/java /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_10
```

Once that is done, add the following to your .bashrc file

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_10 export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib

For [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean):

Comment: Thank you for this complete and detailed answer you have helped me a lot

Comment: Yes, I solved my problem, my version of javac was too old!

Answer (score 2):

You most likely are missing an implementation of JavaFX. On most Linux distributions JavaFX is packages separate from the JDK. The package is most likely called openjfx or something similar.

If you are using Debian or a Debian based distribution such as Ubuntu you should be able to install openjfx by running:

$ sudo apt-get install openjfx